# Exclude a path from WordPress using .htaccess redirects (Apache)

Tags: redirect, apache

I'd like to exclude a path that matches a rule from booting WordPress. The normal way I'd approach this is using the last flag `[L]` in a rule before all the others.

To keep things simple in this example, I'll just pretend I want to match a simple path `/foo/`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
```

```
RewriteRule ^foo/?$ - [L]
```

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, this does not work.
A few other options are suggested in this older [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322559/htaccess-wordpress-exclude-folder-from-rewriterule/2350305), but none of them work (neither for myself nor anyone in the comments of that post).

I did try this rewrite condition instead of the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(foo/.*)$
```

As well as adding `ErrorDocument 401 default` to the end of the `.htaccess` document.

Comment: How exactly is it not working? Is WordPress showing its error 404 page?

Comment: Yeah, the redirect just fails, so if the page exists it goes to `/foo`, if the page doesn't exist it displays the theme's 404. Basically the rule doesn't preclude Wordpress from being routed to.

Comment: I'm actually also getting the error 404, but that should be the expected outcome in my case since the path (`/foo`) doesn't exist and the rewrite is not being redirected to any scripts. Try deactivating plugins and/or try a default theme? Edit: I mean, I'm seeing the default error page that's served by Apache and not WordPress.

Comment: Just tried with all plugins disabled and twenty-nineteen theme (my theme is custom anyway and I don't use plugins much). No luck though. Which rule from above are you using? `RewriteRule ^foo/?$ - [L]`? Where in the `.htaccess` read sequence did you put it?

Comment: Yes, the `RewriteRule ^foo/?$ - [L]` and I put it in the exact same place as in the question - below the `RewriteEngine On`. But that `IfModule` block is the *only* content of my `.htaccess` file. Could it be a caching issue? Try clearing your browser and site cache, and try a different browser as well, and see if that helps?

Comment: Shouldn't be caching because this should all be server side. But also I tried a random rule and _it does_ work, so the `.htaccess` rules _do work_ within that file. I tried removing everything else and still no luck. I'm just curious, which Apache are you running? Can you do `apache2 -v` or `httpd -v`?

Comment: No I can't, not on that server. But I'm running Apache/2.4.26 (Red Hat). And on another server (`httpd -v` = `Apache/2.4.39 (Unix)`), the rewrite rule also worked.

Comment: Thanks for testing, must be something in my `apache` config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One small hiccup is that you'll need to update `RewriteRule ./` in that second to last line. Here is an updated (and tested) snippet for you:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I tested both:

- https://www.domain.com/foo/
- https://www.domain.com/foo/bar/

Hope that helps!!

Comment: That was it, thank you. Although I'm not sure why `.` wouldn't match `./`, it should have matched both. For anyone else having this issue in the future: I optimized slightly by changing to `./?` and wrote a quick service to check the `.htaccess` file and make sure some plugins or updates didn't overwrite/reset it.

Comment: @Orun not a good idea to set a service which disallows modification for the file. instead, only that part should be monitored, because many useful plugins write some other blocks, which shouldnt be disallowed.

Comment: Yeah I agree. The file is still totally writable. I actually already had a service that writes my own block to `.htaccess` within my theme, so I just extended that. It only looks for a particular line, modifies it if a condition is met and then logs the modification in a special log.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `RewriteCond` instead of `RewriteRule`. Use this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/foo/
```

So, for example, the full code could be like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/foo/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

The following rule works for me

```
RewriteRule ^(foo)($|/) - [L]
```

meaning, any path beginning with *foo* like */foo/*, */foo/bar/* or whatever, leads to the Apache 404 instead of the themes 404; under the assumption that there is no actual directory with that path.

The rule has to be before the last standard line of the WordPress block:

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

And it doesn't really matter, if it is after `RewriteBase /`, it can be before it; it was previously just hastily and sloppily worded on my part.

Which would give you the chance to leave the block between `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` untouched, if you'd like to do so. By putting

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^(foo)($|/) - [L]
</IfModule>
```

in front of `# BEGIN WordPress`.

You might want to prevent the path */foo/* from being created in WordPress, this came to mind:

```
add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug', 'no_more_foo_wp_unique_post_slug', 2, 6 );
function no_more_foo_wp_unique_post_slug( 
  $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug 
) {
  if ( $post_parent === 0 ) {
    $pattern = '/^foo$/';
    $replace = 'bar';
    $slug   = preg_replace( $pattern, $replace, $slug );
  }
  return $slug;
}
```

Comment: You're right that I should have set my rule _after_ the base, not sure why I did it before in this post! Actually in the production `.htaccess` it was set after. Thanks for mentioning though. It was an oversight from me when I was editing the markdown here.

Comment: @Orun I clarified my answer a bit.